# zend framework, in which path i can store the profile picture or other user uploaded images

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have to store the user profile picture and other images, what end users are uploading from their end.

What is the path i have to store those images,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

As profile pictures need to be accessed by users, they need to be stored in the `public` folder. This is the only folder that can be read by anyone (or should be).

Zend 2 already has a folder for images (`public/img`) so you might want to use a folder like `public/img/user/avatar`, maybe with subfolders. But everything besides using the `public` folder is entirely up to you.

For files that should not be accessible by anyone, create your own folder outside of `public` (e.g. `cache`, `logs` or simply `data`).

Comment: This is certainly a workable solution for a small site, but as soon as this project moves to multi-server, this falls apart. Uploading user assets to a service like Amazon Cloudfront or even Amazon S3 allows your application server to remain stateless.